# Ruby extend time class through another

Tags: ruby, class, model, module

I'm trying to retrieve the tax rate based on the timestamp. It doesn't make sense to me to do a simple mixin where I define "tax_rate" in the Time class. It makes more sense to put "tax_rate" in a "Government" class (or module? I don't know I'm new to this) and simply have the method be available to the Time class with an option to assume the current time if used on its own.

examples:

`Time.now.tax_rate` == `0.13`
`10.years_ago.tax_rate` == `0.10`
`Government.tax_rate` == `0.13` (assumes Time.now)

Where the method tax_rate is as follows:

```
def self.tax_rate
  t = self || Time.now # I know this part won't work properly, I'll fix it later. I want it to default to using the current Time object or if the method is used on its own, the current time.
  return 0.10 if t < Time.parse("July 1, 2001")
  return 0.12 if t < Time.parse("July 1, 2010")
  0.13
end
```

I basically need to reference tax rates in different classes in my rails project and I feel that putting it straight into one of the models just doesn't fit right. It needs to be on its own.

Comment: So what? what is your question?

Comment: My question is how do I do it? Do I make a single class called "Government"? How do I specify that certain methods are available to the time class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just have a `TaxRate` module?

```
module TaxRate
  def self.get t = Time.now
    t = Time.parse(t) if t.kind_of?(String)
    case
    when t < Time.parse("July 1, 2001") then 0.10
    when t < Time.parse("July 1, 2010") then 0.12
    else 0.13
    end
  end
end

TaxRate.get #=> 0.13
TaxRate.get(Time.now) #=> 0.13
TaxRate.get("July 1, 2000") #=> 0.10
TaxRate.get("July 1, 2012") #=> 0.13
TaxRate.get(10.years_ago) #=> 1.10
```

If you want to define `tax_rate` on `Time`, which I think is unnatural, then, just monkey patch `Time`.

```
class Time
  def tax_rate
    case
    when self < Time.parse("July 1, 2001") then 0.10
    when self < Time.parse("July 1, 2010") then 0.12
    else 0.13
    end
  end
end

Time.now.tax_rate #=> 0.13
10.years_ago.tax_rate #=> 0.10
```

Comment: It's more of just coding preference that I'd rather get the tax_rate OF the date rather than using the date as an argument all the time. I suppose then I'd have to make a separate mixin that references this module? There's no way to do it from within the module itself?